# Advice on linking to code repositories for examples

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, best-practices

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264384/how-do-i-use-ioctl-to-manipulate-my-kernel-module/2264456#2264456) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264384/how-do-i-use-ioctl-to-manipulate-my-kernel-module). In the answer, I am suggesting that the OP take a look at some code that exists in the Linux kernel to use as an example, in particular `drivers/watchdog/softdog.c`.

This brought up a minor dilemma as I was considering editing my answer to make the file reference a link. Should I link to the raw file (the content of the link will change over time, possibly out-dating my answer) or should I link to the revision tip of the file that I was referencing, which again may obsolete the answer if the file changes significantly?

While yes, softdog is unlikely to move much, it is a question worth asking. How do you handle linking to files for example purposes that are also under version control and likely to change?

I realize that SO is heavily edited, but I don't think any system exists (or could conceivably exist) to ensure that answers remain current and accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link to the revision as it was when you posted your answer, and mention the fact that you've done so in your answer. I'd rather have an out-dated answer, clearly flagged as such, than an answer that links to some line in a file which is no longer what the answer was talking about.

Comment: Yeah, best way to go. Thanks :)